# Selenium - Unable to get Exception/Failure if the WebElement is not available on Page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, element

I know this question has been asked many times on this forum. However, i am posting this again after trying out all the solutions i found on site & other resources.
Atlast i need to post this on forum for help.

My product is an web content filter which allow user to browse internet or filter it (based on permissions he has).

So my test case is for a user who can view or cannot view a page based on permissions granted to him.

Valid Test Case is
If user has permission he can view page, this works fine as selenium is able to detect element & move forward. I had used assertion in this case around try catch block(after that i tried lot of other stuff as well)

Invalid Test Case is
If the user doesnt have permission he cannot view the page. So whenever he tries to go to any blacklisted site he gets a page for being blocked(this page is completely different page).
So i know that the element the selenium is trying to find is not there in this case. But during execution my script just gets stuck & doesn't catch exception & move forward.
Tried debugging & over there as well it stops when the line to search the element comes.
I was expecting the script would move forward after catching exception.
I would like to see this test case as failed as well.

One of my friend suggested to check with developer whether the element was present in DOM. I am not sure what difference it would make.(Any pointers on that will help me learn)

Below given is the stuff which i tried in my code

Snippet 1

```
public static void main(String[] args){
-------some code---
System.out.println("User Logs in");
d1.get("http://www.maxim.com");
System.out.println("Site will be Blocked");
Assert.assertTrue(doesElementExist(By.id("block-system-user-menu")));
d1.quit();
}
public static boolean doesElementExist(By locator) {
if (d1.findElements(locator).size() > 0) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

---

Snippet 2

```
d1.get("http://www.maxim.com");
By myLocator = By.id("block-system-user-menu");
if (isElementPresent(myLocator)) {
WebElement myElement = d1.findElement(myLocator);
myElement.getText();
     } 

public static boolean isElementPresent(By locator) {
return d1.findElements(locator).size() > 0;
}
```

---

Snippet 3

```
private static boolean verifyElementAbsent() throws Exception {
try {
d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block-system-user-menu']/div/div/ul/li/a"));
System.out.println("Element Present");
return false;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
System.out.println("Element absent");
return true;
}
```

---

Snippet 4

```
d1.get("http://www.maxim.com");
String S1 = "//*[@id='block-system-user-menu']/div/div/ul/li/a";
verifyElementAbsent(S1);
d1.quit();
}
private static boolean verifyElementAbsent(String locator) throws Exception {
boolean visible = d1.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).isDisplayed();
boolean result = !visible;
System.out.println(result);
return result;
```

---

Snippet 5

```
boolean titleTextfield = d1.findElement(By.id("block-system-user-menu")).isDisplayed();
Assert.assertFalse(titleTextfield, "Title text field present which is not expected");
```

---

Snippet 6

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(d1,    20);WebElementelement2=wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("block-system-user-menu")));
```

---

Snippet 7

```
isElementPresent(By.id("block-system-user-menu"));
public static boolean isElementPresent(By by){
try{
d1.findElement(by);
return true;
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
return false;
}
}
```

---

Snippet 8

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

---

Snippet 9

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.yourLocator).size() > 0
```

---

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Amar

Comment: as your friend suggested, If your DOM is not ready then try to put it in sleep for some milliseconds or wait for that element to be displayed.

Comment: Tried that & it didn't work. I am just curious how people handle this kind of situation when a completely new page comes & selenium tries to find object on that.